# Combine 2 div lines into 1

Tags: html, css, footer

How can I combine these two lines into one? I want them both to display on the footer on the same line instead of on top of each other; the copyright on the left side and the seal on the right side

```
<div align="left">
  © Copyright 2015
</div>

<div align="right"; id="siteseal"><script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?
sealID=uCXy8FY4wxQSQ6UQxA9hMdKU7bpt6msZcKVOa4W04tulP31if83EsCcPWG4P">
</script></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

on the first div

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

on the second div

```
style="display:block; float:right"
```

Here is an example :

```
<body>
    <div id=footer style="width:80%; margin:auto; background-color:rgb(50,50,50);">
        <div style="display:inline-block; color:white; padding-left:20px">
            © Copyright 2015
        </div>
        <div style="display:block; float:right; color:white; padding-right:20px">
            Fundhor
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works but it overrides the alignment and pushes them together.  I'm trying to get the Copyright on the far left side of the page and the seal on the far right side of the page.

Comment: maybe just use a "float:right;" on the second div then

Comment: I added an example for you to see. If it helped make sure to mark your question as answered ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work